# C++ Bindings and OpenCL implies Error clCreateKernel : -46

Tags: c++, opencl

I try to access a opencl kernel implementation out of a c++ program.
I get an error, compiling my c++ program:

> clCreateKernel : -46

My C++ program is

```
#define __CL_ENABLE_EXCEPTIONS

#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <CL/cl.hpp>
#include <CL/opencl.h>

using namespace std; int main () {

    vector<cl::Platform> platforms;
    vector<cl::Device> devices;
    vector<cl::Kernel> kernels;

    try {

        // create platform
        cl::Platform::get(&platforms);
        platforms[0].getDevices(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, &devices);

        // create context
        cl::Context context(devices);

        // create command queue
        cl::CommandQueue queue(context, devices[0]);

        // load opencl source
        ifstream cl_file("pbkdf2_hmac_sha1_unsplit_kernel.cl");
        string cl_string(istreambuf_iterator<char>(cl_file), (istreambuf_iterator<char>()));
        cl::Program::Sources source(1, make_pair(cl_string.c_str(), 
            cl_string.length() + 1));

        // create program
        cl::Program program(context, source);

        // compile opencl source
        program.build(devices);

        // load named kernel from opencl source
        cl::Kernel kernel(program, "PBKDF2");

        // create a message to send to kernel ----------------------------------------------------------------
        char* password = "C & OpenCL is cool";
        //unsigned int keyBytes = 18; // keyBytes
        cl_uint keyBytes = 18; // keyBytes  

        char* passwordSalt = "12345678901234567890123456789012";
        cl_uint passwordSaltLen = 32;

//        cl_int passwordIterations = 2;
        cl_uint passwordIterations = 2;

        cl_uint bufferC_size = 20;

        // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // allocate device buffer to hold message
        cl::Buffer bufferA(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, sizeof(char) * keyBytes, password);
        cl::Buffer bufferB(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, sizeof(char) * passwordSaltLen, passwordSalt);
        cl::Buffer bufferC(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, sizeof(char) * keyBytes);

        queue.enqueueWriteBuffer(bufferA, CL_TRUE, 0, keyBytes * sizeof(char), password);
        queue.enqueueWriteBuffer(bufferB, CL_TRUE, 0, passwordSaltLen * sizeof(char), passwordSalt);

/* inline void pbkdf2(__global const uchar * pass, uint passlen,
                   __global const uchar * salt, uint saltlen, uint iterations,
                   __global uint * out, uint outlen)
*/
        // set message as kernel argument
        kernel.setArg(0, bufferA);
        kernel.setArg(1, keyBytes);
        kernel.setArg(2, bufferB);
        kernel.setArg(3, passwordSaltLen); // saltlen
        kernel.setArg(4, passwordIterations);
        kernel.setArg(5, bufferC);
        kernel.setArg(6, bufferC_size);

         // execute kernel
        queue.enqueueTask(kernel);

        // wait for completion
        queue.finish();
        // ----------------------
        char* out_global = "                 !";    queue.enqueueReadBuffer(bufferC, CL_TRUE, 0, keyBytes * sizeof(char), out_global);
        cout << "Output " << out_global << endl;
        // ----------------------
        cout << endl;

    } catch (cl::Error e) {
        cout << endl << e.what() << " : " << e.err() << endl;
    }

    return 0;
     }
```

I am trying to use the implementation of the following opencl program:

```
/*
 * This software is Copyright (c) 2012 Lukas Odzioba <ukasz@openwall.net>
 * and Copyright (c) 2012 magnum
 * and it is hereby released to the general public under the following terms:
 * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
 * modification, are permitted.
 *
 * Pass this kernel -DKEYLEN=x -DOUTLEN=y -DSALTLEN=z for generic use.
 *
 * KEYLEN  should be PLAINTEXT_LENGTH for passwords or 20 for hash
 * OUTLEN  should be sizeof(outbuffer->v)
 * SALTLEN should be sizeof(currentsalt.salt)
 */

#define KEYLEN 20
#define OUTLEN 77
#define SALTLEN 32

#include "opencl_device_info.h"

/* Macros for reading/writing chars from int32's */
#if gpu_amd(DEVICE_INFO) || no_byte_addressable(DEVICE_INFO)
/* These use 32-bit stores */
#define XORCHAR_BE(buf, index, val) (buf)[(index)>>2] = ((buf)[(index)>>2]) ^ ((val) << ((((index) & 3) ^ 3) << 3))
#define PUTCHAR(buf, index, val) (buf)[(index)>>2] = ((buf)[(index)>>2] & ~(0xffU << (((index) & 3) << 3))) + ((val) << (((index) & 3) << 3))
#define PUTCHAR_BE(buf, index, val) (buf)[(index)>>2] = ((buf)[(index)>>2] & ~(0xffU << ((((index) & 3) ^ 3) << 3))) + ((val) << ((((index) & 3) ^ 3) << 3))
#define PUTCHAR_G   PUTCHAR
#define PUTCHAR_BE_G    PUTCHAR_BE
#else
/* These use byte-adressed stores */
#define XORCHAR_BE(buf, index, val) ((uchar*)(buf))[(index) ^ 3] ^= (val)
#define PUTCHAR(buf, index, val) ((uchar*)(buf))[(index)] = (val)
#define PUTCHAR_G(buf, index, val) ((__global uchar*)(buf))[(index)] = (val)
#define PUTCHAR_BE(buf, index, val) ((uchar*)(buf))[(index) ^ 3] = (val)
#define PUTCHAR_BE_G(buf, index, val) ((__global uchar*)(buf))[(index) ^ 3] = (val)
#endif

#ifdef SCALAR
inline uint SWAP32(uint x)
{
    x = rotate(x, 16U);
    return ((x & 0x00FF00FF) << 8) + ((x >> 8) & 0x00FF00FF);
}
#else
#define SWAP32(a)   (as_uint(as_uchar4(a).wzyx))
#endif

#define INIT_A          0x67452301
#define INIT_B          0xefcdab89
#define INIT_C          0x98badcfe
#define INIT_D          0x10325476
#define INIT_E          0xc3d2e1f0

#define SQRT_2          0x5a827999
#define SQRT_3          0x6ed9eba1

#define SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH  20

#define K1          0x5a827999
#define K2          0x6ed9eba1
#define K3          0x8f1bbcdc
#define K4          0xca62c1d6

#ifdef USE_BITSELECT
#define F1(x,y,z)   bitselect(z, y, x)
#else
#define F1(x,y,z)   (z ^ (x & (y ^ z)))
#endif
#define F2(x,y,z)   (x ^ y ^ z)
#ifdef USE_BITSELECT
#define F3(x,y,z)   (bitselect(x, y, z) ^ bitselect(x, 0U, y))
#else
#define F3(x,y,z)   ((x & y) | (z & (x | y)))
#endif
#define F4(x,y,z)   (x ^ y ^ z)

#ifndef GET_WORD_32_BE
#define GET_WORD_32_BE(n,b,i)                           \
{                                                       \
    (n) = ( (unsigned long) (b)[(i)    ] << 24 )        \
        | ( (unsigned long) (b)[(i) + 1] << 16 )        \
        | ( (unsigned long) (b)[(i) + 2] <<  8 )        \
        | ( (unsigned long) (b)[(i) + 3]       );       \
}
#endif

#ifndef PUT_WORD_32_BE
#define PUT_WORD_32_BE(n,b,i)                           \
{                                                       \
    (b)[(i)    ] = (unsigned char) ( (n) >> 24 );       \
    (b)[(i) + 1] = (unsigned char) ( (n) >> 16 );       \
    (b)[(i) + 2] = (unsigned char) ( (n) >>  8 );       \
    (b)[(i) + 3] = (unsigned char) ( (n)       );       \
}
#endif

#if 0
#define S(x, n) (rotate((x), (uint)(n)))
#else
#define S(x, n) ((x << n) | ((x) >> (32 - n)))
#endif

#define R(t)                                            \
(                                                       \
    temp = W[(t -  3) & 0x0F] ^ W[(t - 8) & 0x0F] ^     \
           W[(t - 14) & 0x0F] ^ W[ t      & 0x0F],      \
    ( W[t & 0x0F] = S(temp,1) )                         \
)

#define R2(t)                                            \
(                                                       \
    S((W[(t -  3) & 0x0F] ^ W[(t - 8) & 0x0F] ^     \
     W[(t - 14) & 0x0F] ^ W[ t      & 0x0F]),1)          \
)

#define P1(a,b,c,d,e,x)                                  \
{                                                       \
    e += S(a,5) + F1(b,c,d) + K1 + x; b = S(b,30);        \
}

#define P2(a,b,c,d,e,x)                                  \
{                                                       \
    e += S(a,5) + F2(b,c,d) + K2 + x; b = S(b,30);        \
}

#define P3(a,b,c,d,e,x)                                  \
{                                                       \
    e += S(a,5) + F3(b,c,d) + K3 + x; b = S(b,30);        \
}

#define P4(a,b,c,d,e,x)                                  \
{                                                       \
    e += S(a,5) + F4(b,c,d) + K4 + x; b = S(b,30);        \
}

#define PZ(a,b,c,d,e)                                  \
{                                                       \
    e += S(a,5) + F1(b,c,d) + K1 ; b = S(b,30);        \
}

#define SHA1(A,B,C,D,E,W) \
    P1(A, B, C, D, E, W[0] );\
    P1(E, A, B, C, D, W[1] );\
    P1(D, E, A, B, C, W[2] );\
    P1(C, D, E, A, B, W[3] );\
    P1(B, C, D, E, A, W[4] );\
    P1(A, B, C, D, E, W[5] );\
    P1(E, A, B, C, D, W[6] );\
    P1(D, E, A, B, C, W[7] );\
    P1(C, D, E, A, B, W[8] );\
    P1(B, C, D, E, A, W[9] );\
    P1(A, B, C, D, E, W[10]);\
    P1(E, A, B, C, D, W[11]);\
    P1(D, E, A, B, C, W[12]);\
    P1(C, D, E, A, B, W[13]);\
    P1(B, C, D, E, A, W[14]);\
    P1(A, B, C, D, E, W[15]);\
    P1(E, A, B, C, D, R(16));\
    P1(D, E, A, B, C, R(17));\
    P1(C, D, E, A, B, R(18));\
    P1(B, C, D, E, A, R(19));\
    P2(A, B, C, D, E, R(20));\
    P2(E, A, B, C, D, R(21));\
    P2(D, E, A, B, C, R(22));\
    P2(C, D, E, A, B, R(23));\
    P2(B, C, D, E, A, R(24));\
    P2(A, B, C, D, E, R(25));\
    P2(E, A, B, C, D, R(26));\
    P2(D, E, A, B, C, R(27));\
    P2(C, D, E, A, B, R(28));\
    P2(B, C, D, E, A, R(29));\
    P2(A, B, C, D, E, R(30));\
    P2(E, A, B, C, D, R(31));\
    P2(D, E, A, B, C, R(32));\
    P2(C, D, E, A, B, R(33));\
    P2(B, C, D, E, A, R(34));\
    P2(A, B, C, D, E, R(35));\
    P2(E, A, B, C, D, R(36));\
    P2(D, E, A, B, C, R(37));\
    P2(C, D, E, A, B, R(38));\
    P2(B, C, D, E, A, R(39));\
    P3(A, B, C, D, E, R(40));\
    P3(E, A, B, C, D, R(41));\
    P3(D, E, A, B, C, R(42));\
    P3(C, D, E, A, B, R(43));\
    P3(B, C, D, E, A, R(44));\
    P3(A, B, C, D, E, R(45));\
    P3(E, A, B, C, D, R(46));\
    P3(D, E, A, B, C, R(47));\
    P3(C, D, E, A, B, R(48));\
    P3(B, C, D, E, A, R(49));\
    P3(A, B, C, D, E, R(50));\
    P3(E, A, B, C, D, R(51));\
    P3(D, E, A, B, C, R(52));\
    P3(C, D, E, A, B, R(53));\
    P3(B, C, D, E, A, R(54));\
    P3(A, B, C, D, E, R(55));\
    P3(E, A, B, C, D, R(56));\
    P3(D, E, A, B, C, R(57));\
    P3(C, D, E, A, B, R(58));\
    P3(B, C, D, E, A, R(59));\
    P4(A, B, C, D, E, R(60));\
    P4(E, A, B, C, D, R(61));\
    P4(D, E, A, B, C, R(62));\
    P4(C, D, E, A, B, R(63));\
    P4(B, C, D, E, A, R(64));\
    P4(A, B, C, D, E, R(65));\
    P4(E, A, B, C, D, R(66));\
    P4(D, E, A, B, C, R(67));\
    P4(C, D, E, A, B, R(68));\
    P4(B, C, D, E, A, R(69));\
    P4(A, B, C, D, E, R(70));\
    P4(E, A, B, C, D, R(71));\
    P4(D, E, A, B, C, R(72));\
    P4(C, D, E, A, B, R(73));\
    P4(B, C, D, E, A, R(74));\
    P4(A, B, C, D, E, R(75));\
    P4(E, A, B, C, D, R(76));\
    P4(D, E, A, B, C, R(77));\
    P4(C, D, E, A, B, R(78));\
    P4(B, C, D, E, A, R(79));

#define SHA2BEG(A,B,C,D,E,W) \
    P1(A, B, C, D, E, W[0]);\
    P1(E, A, B, C, D, W[1]);\
    P1(D, E, A, B, C, W[2]);\
    P1(C, D, E, A, B, W[3]);\
    P1(B, C, D, E, A, W[4]);\
    P1(A, B, C, D, E, W[5]);\
    PZ(E, A, B, C, D);\
    PZ(D, E, A, B, C);\
    PZ(C, D, E, A, B);\
    PZ(B, C, D, E, A);\
    PZ(A, B, C, D, E);\
    PZ(E, A, B, C, D);\
    PZ(D, E, A, B, C);\
    PZ(C, D, E, A, B);\
    PZ(B, C, D, E, A);\
    P1(A, B, C, D, E, W[15]);\

#define Q16 (W[0] = S((W[2] ^ W[0]),1))
#define Q17 (W[1] = S((W[3] ^ W[1]),1))
#define Q18 (W[2] = S((W[15] ^ W[4] ^ W[2]),1))
#define Q19 (W[3] = S((W[0]  ^ W[5] ^ W[3]),1))
#define Q20 (W[4] = S((W[1]  ^ W[4]),1))
#define Q21 (W[5] = S((W[2] ^ W[5]),1))
#define Q22 (W[6] = S(W[3],1))
#define Q23 (W[7] = S((W[4] ^ W[15]),1))
#define Q24 (W[8] = S((W[5] ^ W[0]),1))
#define Q25 (W[9] = S((W[6] ^ W[1]),1))
#define Q26 (W[10] = S((W[7] ^ W[2]),1))
#define Q27 (W[11] = S((W[8] ^ W[3]),1))
#define Q28 (W[12] = S((W[9] ^ W[4]),1))
#define Q29 (W[13] = S((W[10] ^ W[5] ^ W[15]),1))
#define Q30 (W[14] = S((W[11] ^ W[6] ^ W[0]),1))
#define SHA2END(A,B,C,D,E,W)\
    P1(E, A, B, C, D, Q16);\
    P1(D, E, A, B, C, Q17);\
    P1(C, D, E, A, B, Q18);\
    P1(B, C, D, E, A, Q19);\
    P2(A, B, C, D, E, Q20);\
    P2(E, A, B, C, D, Q21);\
    P2(D, E, A, B, C, Q22);\
    P2(C, D, E, A, B, Q23);\
    P2(B, C, D, E, A, Q24);\
    P2(A, B, C, D, E, Q25);\
    P2(E, A, B, C, D, Q26);\
    P2(D, E, A, B, C, Q27);\
    P2(C, D, E, A, B, Q28);\
    P2(B, C, D, E, A, Q29);\
    P2(A, B, C, D, E, Q30);\
    P2(E, A, B, C, D, R(31));\
    P2(D, E, A, B, C, R(32));\
    P2(C, D, E, A, B, R(33));\
    P2(B, C, D, E, A, R(34));\
    P2(A, B, C, D, E, R(35));\
    P2(E, A, B, C, D, R(36));\
    P2(D, E, A, B, C, R(37));\
    P2(C, D, E, A, B, R(38));\
    P2(B, C, D, E, A, R(39));\
    P3(A, B, C, D, E, R(40));\
    P3(E, A, B, C, D, R(41));\
    P3(D, E, A, B, C, R(42));\
    P3(C, D, E, A, B, R(43));\
    P3(B, C, D, E, A, R(44));\
    P3(A, B, C, D, E, R(45));\
    P3(E, A, B, C, D, R(46));\
    P3(D, E, A, B, C, R(47));\
    P3(C, D, E, A, B, R(48));\
    P3(B, C, D, E, A, R(49));\
    P3(A, B, C, D, E, R(50));\
    P3(E, A, B, C, D, R(51));\
    P3(D, E, A, B, C, R(52));\
    P3(C, D, E, A, B, R(53));\
    P3(B, C, D, E, A, R(54));\
    P3(A, B, C, D, E, R(55));\
    P3(E, A, B, C, D, R(56));\
    P3(D, E, A, B, C, R(57));\
    P3(C, D, E, A, B, R(58));\
    P3(B, C, D, E, A, R(59));\
    P4(A, B, C, D, E, R(60));\
    P4(E, A, B, C, D, R(61));\
    P4(D, E, A, B, C, R(62));\
    P4(C, D, E, A, B, R(63));\
    P4(B, C, D, E, A, R(64));\
    P4(A, B, C, D, E, R(65));\
    P4(E, A, B, C, D, R(66));\
    P4(D, E, A, B, C, R(67));\
    P4(C, D, E, A, B, R(68));\
    P4(B, C, D, E, A, R(69));\
    P4(A, B, C, D, E, R(70));\
    P4(E, A, B, C, D, R(71));\
    P4(D, E, A, B, C, R(72));\
    P4(C, D, E, A, B, R(73));\
    P4(B, C, D, E, A, R(74));\
    P4(A, B, C, D, E, R(75));\
    P4(E, A, B, C, D, R(76));\
    P4(D, E, A, B, C, R2(77));\
    P4(C, D, E, A, B, R2(78));\
    P4(B, C, D, E, A, R2(79));

#define  SHA2(A,B,C,D,E,W) SHA2BEG(A,B,C,D,E,W) SHA2END(A,B,C,D,E,W)


typedef struct {
    uint length;
    uchar v[KEYLEN];
} pbkdf2_password;

typedef struct {
    uint v[(OUTLEN+3)/4];
} pbkdf2_hash;

typedef struct {
//  uchar length;
    unsigned int length;
    uchar salt[SALTLEN];
    uint iterations;
    uint outlen;
} pbkdf2_salt;

inline void preproc(__global const uchar * key, uint keylen,
    __private uint * state, uint padding)
{
    uint i;
    uint W[16], temp;

    for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        W[i] = padding;

    for (i = 0; i < keylen; i++)
        XORCHAR_BE(W, i, key[i]);

    uint A = INIT_A;
    uint B = INIT_B;
    uint C = INIT_C;
    uint D = INIT_D;
    uint E = INIT_E;

    SHA1(A, B, C, D, E, W);

    state[0] = A + INIT_A;
    state[1] = B + INIT_B;
    state[2] = C + INIT_C;
    state[3] = D + INIT_D;
    state[4] = E + INIT_E;

}

inline void hmac_sha1(__private uint * output,
    __private uint * ipad_state,
    __private uint * opad_state,
    __global const uchar * salt, int saltlen, uchar add)
{
    int i;
    uint temp, W[16];
    uint A, B, C, D, E;
    uchar buf[64];
    uint *src = (uint *) buf;
    i = 64 / 4;
    while (i--)
        *src++ = 0;
    //_memcpy(buf, salt, saltlen);
    for (i = 0; i < saltlen; i++)
        buf[i] = salt[i];

    buf[saltlen + 4] = 0x80;
    buf[saltlen + 3] = add;
    PUT_WORD_32_BE((64 + saltlen + 4) << 3, buf, 60);

    A = ipad_state[0];
    B = ipad_state[1];
    C = ipad_state[2];
    D = ipad_state[3];
    E = ipad_state[4];

    for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        GET_WORD_32_BE(W[i], buf, i * 4);

    SHA1(A, B, C, D, E, W);

    A += ipad_state[0];
    B += ipad_state[1];
    C += ipad_state[2];
    D += ipad_state[3];
    E += ipad_state[4];

    PUT_WORD_32_BE(A, buf, 0);
    PUT_WORD_32_BE(B, buf, 4);
    PUT_WORD_32_BE(C, buf, 8);
    PUT_WORD_32_BE(D, buf, 12);
    PUT_WORD_32_BE(E, buf, 16);
    PUT_WORD_32_BE(0, buf, 20);
    PUT_WORD_32_BE(0, buf, 24);


    buf[20] = 0x80;
    PUT_WORD_32_BE(0x2A0, buf, 60);

    A = opad_state[0];
    B = opad_state[1];
    C = opad_state[2];
    D = opad_state[3];
    E = opad_state[4];

    for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        GET_WORD_32_BE(W[i], buf, i * 4);

    SHA1(A, B, C, D, E, W);

    A += opad_state[0];
    B += opad_state[1];
    C += opad_state[2];
    D += opad_state[3];
    E += opad_state[4];

    output[0] = A;
    output[1] = B;
    output[2] = C;
    output[3] = D;
    output[4] = E;
}



inline void big_hmac_sha1(__private uint * input, uint inputlen,
    __private uint * ipad_state,
    __private uint * opad_state, __private uint * tmp_out, int iterations)
{
    int i, lo;
    uint temp, W[16];
    uint A, B, C, D, E;

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        W[i] = input[i];

    for (lo = 1; lo < iterations; lo++) {

        A = ipad_state[0];
        B = ipad_state[1];
        C = ipad_state[2];
        D = ipad_state[3];
        E = ipad_state[4];

        W[5] = 0x80000000;
        W[15] = 0x2A0;

        SHA2(A, B, C, D, E, W);

        A += ipad_state[0];
        B += ipad_state[1];
        C += ipad_state[2];
        D += ipad_state[3];
        E += ipad_state[4];

        W[0] = A;
        W[1] = B;
        W[2] = C;
        W[3] = D;
        W[4] = E;
        W[5] = 0x80000000;
        W[15] = 0x2A0;

        A = opad_state[0];
        B = opad_state[1];
        C = opad_state[2];
        D = opad_state[3];
        E = opad_state[4];

        SHA2(A, B, C, D, E, W);

        A += opad_state[0];
        B += opad_state[1];
        C += opad_state[2];
        D += opad_state[3];
        E += opad_state[4];

        W[0] = A;
        W[1] = B;
        W[2] = C;
        W[3] = D;
        W[4] = E;

        tmp_out[0] ^= A;
        tmp_out[1] ^= B;
        tmp_out[2] ^= C;
        tmp_out[3] ^= D;
        tmp_out[4] ^= E;
    }
}

inline void pbkdf2(__global const uchar * pass, uint passlen,
                   __global const uchar * salt, uint saltlen, uint iterations,
                   __global uint * out, uint outlen)
{
    uint ipad_state[5];
    uint opad_state[5];
    uint r, t = 0;

    preproc(pass, passlen, ipad_state, 0x36363636);
    preproc(pass, passlen, opad_state, 0x5c5c5c5c);

    for (r = 1; r <= (outlen + 19) / 20; r++) {
        uint tmp_out[5];
        int i;

        hmac_sha1(tmp_out, ipad_state, opad_state, salt, saltlen, r);

        big_hmac_sha1(tmp_out, SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH,
                      ipad_state, opad_state,
                      tmp_out, iterations);

        for (i = 0; i < 20 && t < (outlen + 3) / 4 * 4; i++, t++)
            PUTCHAR_BE_G(out, t, ((uchar*)tmp_out)[i]);
    }
}

__kernel void derive_key(__global const pbkdf2_password *inbuffer,
    __global pbkdf2_hash *outbuffer, __global const pbkdf2_salt *salt)
{
    uint idx = get_global_id(0);

    pbkdf2(inbuffer[idx].v, inbuffer[idx].length,
           salt->salt, salt->length,
           salt->iterations, outbuffer[idx].v, salt->outlen);
}
```

Can you tell me, what I do wrong?

Maybe you can also tell me, where I can find a kind of table reference for opencl error messages and its meanings.

Thank you.
Regards,
Marcus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In opencl it is

```
inline void pbkdf2(__global const uchar * pass, uint passlen,
                   __global const uchar * salt, uint saltlen, uint iterations,
                   __global uint * out, uint outlen)
```

So, by calling (watch case sensitifity)

```
cl::Kernel kernel(program, "pbkdf2");
```

I try to call a non-kernel function, which does not exist.

Solution:

Change the function declaration to

```
__kernel void pbkdf2(__global const uchar * pass, uint passlen,
                   __global const uchar * salt, uint saltlen, uint iterations,
                   __global uint * out, uint outlen)
```

Alright, now it is working!
But now I am getting a segmentation fault, that can be fixed by right casting:

```
const char* pwd = "C & OpenCL is cool";
cl_uchar * password = (cl_uchar*) &pwd;
const char* pwdSalt = "12345678901234567890123456789012";
cl_uchar* passwordSalt =  (cl_uchar*) &pwdSalt;
```

And of course, right cl:Buffer parameters:

```
   cl::Buffer bufferA(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, sizeof(cl_uchar) * keyBytes, password);
    cl::Buffer bufferB(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, sizeof(cl_uchar) * passwordSaltLen, passwordSalt);
```

Well done.

Answer (score 3):

Error -46 is CL_INVALID_KERNEL_NAME

`#define CL_INVALID_KERNEL_NAME                      -46`

In your .cl the name is `pbkdf2` but in your C++ file you have `PBKDF2`, as the name (didn't try building it, but I believe it's case sensitive).

OpenCL documentation can be found at http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/ .  They have PDFs, html docs, and header files.

Comment: The error is correct, and you are right, that there is a case sensibility problem, BUT the called kernel isn't a kernel. It is an inline function.